# How to retry ActionMQ Connection using IP alone, without involving DNS resolution?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I've a requirement where the Action MQ Client 5.9 will connect to the server using IP address, and then upon Broker reboot, it must reconnect to the server again (sort of maintenance windows for MQ Server).

I am following the references from here:
http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html 
http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-auto-reconnection.html

and my connection string looks like this: `failover:(tcp://10.1.23.11:61616)`

I get the below error:

```
ERROR | Failed to Lookup INetAddress for URI[nio://abcde-vm-23-99:61616]: {}
java.net.UnknownHostException: abcde-vm-23-99
           at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
           at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
```

It appears like IP to hostname resolution is being attempted and it fails there. However, this behavior is not seen if failover is not given in the connection string. Eg: `tcp://10.1.23.11:61616` works.

I understand that having host file entries for IP to hostname might work here or having a proper DNS setup can resolve this, but unfortunately both are not desirable in our setup.

Comment: Where is `nio://abcde-vm-23-99:61616` being picked up from in your config?

Comment: @user3788685, `abcde-vm-23-99` is the hostname defined on the MQ Server. I am not sure, why a hostname resolution is attempted at the client end when only the IP address is provided.